# MVVM in an Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, mvvm

For the first few months in my career, I was learning and writing Angular applications and oftentimes, binding to properties in my components by calling functions.

For example (simple example):

```
<div *ngFor="let animal of animals">
    <img [src]="animal.getAnimalSrc()">
    <button [disable]="animal.disableAnimal()">
</div>
```

I was told that calling functions like this in my template was not too good of an idea because of Angular's [lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and [docheck](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#docheck).

So I instead began going for more of a MVVM approach and in my component code doing something like:

```
private toAnimalViewModel(value: any): object {
    return {
        animalSrc: this.getAnimalSrc();
        disableAnimal: this.disableAnimal();
    };
}
```

And then in my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let animal of animals">
    <img [src]="animal.animalSrc">
    <button [disable]="animal.disableAnimal">
</div>
```

I was wondering why this is considered better practice (is it?) and what are some of the pros/cons of writing code in this fashion.

Thanks

Comment: the first example seems way better to use, its cleaner and easier to see that youre using functions to return values

Comment: One of the cons of using functions in templates, is that you have to be extremely careful with what you do in them. Each time Angular runs change detection, the function is run, and If the function in turn makes changes that triggers change detection, you might create a wave of changes that'll unintentionally hurt performance. Worst case it may cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen, so by instead calculating all of my values once and binding to a ViewModel, I can essentially skip the change detection?

Comment: The change detection is run anyway, but instead of calling a function each time, that is quite slow, only the value is checked. You have less risk to make mistakes that could lower performances or make everything going wrong (like in the case of infinite loops, when the returned value changes every time you call the function)